# What time format is "05/29:00:45"?

Tags: time, format, utc

An API returned time in this format:

"05/29:00:45"?

It was probably manually entered.

I understand how to parse it but is this a common time format in some countries or software?

Answer (score 0):

the format is month/Day and time (hours/second). Probably the correct format it will be 05/29/00:45